# matlab: how to set dynamically invisible what is visible

Tags: matlab, user-interface, properties, visible, matlab-uitable

I  have a simple question about matlab using interface.
I found that if I first declare an object (for example a table with the command UI table) NOT visible and after I make it visible, it works i.e. I see effectively in the figure the modification.
On the contrary, and here it's my problem, If I first declare an object visible and after I make it NOT visible, it doesn't work i.e. I not obtain the invisibility of the object.

Making an example:

```
figure;
h_tabell=uitable(gcf,'vis','off','data',randn(3));
h_tabell=uitable(gcf,'vis','on','data',randn(3)); %
```

here I see that the table is now visible

%Now I want make it that table invisible again, with
`set(h_tabell,'vis','off') %` here I see that the table already is visible

I need it, because in my program, the object is visible and if the user needs, I want to  to set invisible the same object.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You should only use the Matlab function `set` to change the properties of your object.

Here you make two calls to `uitable`, so here is what really happen if you break it down:

- the first call create an invisible table
- the second call create another table (overwriting the variable `h_tabell` with the new handle) but this time visible

You can verify this by checking that your figure now have two children:

```
children=get(gcf,'children');
```

Now if you try to change the visible property of the object referenced by the handle h_tabell, it will only apply to the second table.

The following piece of code works as expected and create only one table:

```
figure;
h_tabell=uitable(gcf,'visible','off','data',randn(3));
% Switch the table to visible
set(h_tabell,'visible','on');
% Switch it back to invisible
set(h_tabell,'visible','off');
```